# how to move a multiple cursor move a with coordinates?

Tags: javascript

I have a socket connection that gives me someone's cursor position. I want to create a cursor for each user that wants to share it like in ( [togetherjs](https://togetherjs.com/) ).

- How to position it in the browser with the coordinates?
- Is there any library in JS that can handle this?

```js
let cursorData = {
  pageX: 0,
  pageY: 0,
  clientX: 0,
  clientY: 0
}
```

Comment: My idea would be to overlay a fixed `<canvas>` and just draw some graphics at the given coordinates. Although I would be curious to know the other users' window sizes. Differences in aspect ratio and resolution would more than likely result in inaccurate representation, if it's based solely on their absolute coordinates.

Comment: I don't need to draw, I need to put a cursor (pointer with a name)